# $or, $in, sort and limit - ridiculously slower than separate queries splitting the $or

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-performance

The query below takes 80+ seconds (!) on an Ubuntu 14 server with SSD, 2 CPUs and 2GB RAM. Mongo 2.4.10, and a collection with ~400k records:

```
db.content.find({
   "$or": [
       {
           "cik": {
               "$in": [
                   "0000794367",
                   "0000867773"
               ]
           }
       },
       {
           "companiesDetected.ids": {
               "$in": [
                   "biFrixuF7BCyrng6p",
                   "cbCrZSEzHYnPa2PwA"
               ]
           }
       }
   ]
}).limit(100).sort({"pubDate": -1, "title": 1})
```

I have indexes on `cik`, `companiesDetected.ids`, `pubDate`, `title`, and a compound index on `{"pubDate": -1, "title": 1}`. Here's the `explain()`:

```
{
    "cursor": "BtreeCursor pubDate_-1_title_1",
    "indexBounds": {
        "pubDate": [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement": 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement": 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "title": [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement": 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement": 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "indexOnly": false,
    "isMultiKey": false,
    "millis": 87903,
    "n": 44,
    "nChunkSkips": 0,
    "nYields": 455,
    "nscanned": 406421,
    "nscannedAllPlans": 406421,
    "nscannedObjects": 406421,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 406421,
    "scanAndOrder": false,
    "server": "localhost:27017"
}
```

What's wrong here?

If I split the query into the two conditions that make up the `$or`, times are under 100ms each.

I've added an index `{"cik":1,"companiesDetected.ids":1,"pubDate": -1, "title": 1}` at [dark_shadow's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886720/or-in-sort-and-limit-ridiculously-slower-than-separate-queries-splitting-t#comment38656882_24886720) and the `explain` on the query takes 111 seconds. Rerunning the query immediately without `explain` takes 101 seconds (did this twice in a row). Without the sort, it takes 33ms (!).

Comment: If you rerun the first query, does it have the same behavior?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your sort

Comment: @Sammaye I am interested in seeing the query's explain a) without the sort and b) with the usage of the other index.

Comment: @xlembouras an explain(true) would be interesting too but I think I might know why, index usage has changed in 2.6+ for $ors with sort. It is not longer as simple as adding 3 indexes

Comment: Try creating this index: {"cik":1,"companiesDetected.ids":1,"pubDate": -1, "title": 1} and then run the query.

Comment: Ah that would explain it then, yep, no sort ranges used in $ors

Comment: Again. Can  we please wait for the "poster" to respond. **Not a chat room**. Go and chat for yourselves. You don't have answers so you are not adding value. This isn't an answer but it at least tells you guys to stop.

Comment: You are suffering from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205

Comment: @DanDascalescu Not about you. Various commentators have warnings posted already about using comments as a chat facility. The general prompt was "please make your question more clear". So glad you did that, it shouldn't have taken 10 comments to do so though. Do you want an answer or are you just looking for arguments? Realise who is  actually helping here. So I ask "slower than what?" What is the alternate query that is faster. Glad others actually asked that.

Comment: @Sammaye - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13754 even?

Comment: @DanDascalescu possibly, without testing hard to say, it seems to be data dependant that one. Though being on 2.4 the one I posted is of greatest problem to you, you could upgrade (if you can atm)

Comment: @DanDascalescu You may also suffer from performance problems here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12024 but since without the sort it is very fast I believe you are not affected by this, though good to keep in mind

Comment: Quoting JIRA issues are not answers. Also why the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24887774/2313887)?

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't see a duplicate, I see a separate problem that has derived from this problem

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that queries involving `$or`, `$in`, `limit` and `sort` suffer from [MongoDB 2.4.x bug/under-optimization](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205) - in particular [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13754) which was fixed in 2.6.2.

Upgrading to 2.6.3 solved the problem and now the query above is **orders of magnitude faster** (usually under 100ms).

(If you were wondering why I wasn't using 2.6.x in the first place, it's because [Meteor doesn't yet support Mongo 2.6](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2036)).